# Are editorconfig files supported in visual studio 2017 for mac?

Tags: visual-studio-mac, editorconfig

Can I use editorconfig files in visual studio 2017 for mac?

Natively or with a third party plugin?

[I only found one old reference, and wasn't supported at that time](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96396/editorconfig-support)

Comment: Not currently. It is planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with VSMac 15.7 released on May 7th, you can.